# Mysql variable is not set at my query

Tags: mysql, sql

I run this code at my workbench:

```
SET @test = 1;

SELECT * FROM dogs_match.posts WHERE dog_type = @test;
```

My problem is: The query is using `@test` as a string and not the variable value.

This is the query that the workbench run:

```
SELECT * FROM dogs_match.posts WHERE dog_type = @test LIMIT 0, 1000
```

How can I make `@test` to be used as variable and not as normal string?

Comment: Why do you think it's using @test as a string? MySQL will always interpret a user-defined variable (beginning with `@` as a variable unless you put in in quotes, as a string literal.  Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the variable inside the SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM dogs_match.posts CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @test := 1) vars
WHERE dog_type = @test;
```